# Data compression algorithms with identical compression and decompression times?

Tags: networking, compression

Is there a compression algorithm, which requires the same amount of computing power and time for both compression and decompression.

This is my problem :

I wish to transfer large files through a low speed network. So I wish to compress data before sending it.

Since the computing power on the sending and receiving system is identical, I wish to save time by having both compression and decompression time to be nearly equal.

Comment: Making compression and decompression times equal is in general not a good way to save time.

Answer (score 0):

The decompression time is irrelevant. The lower the speed of your network, the more time you would want to spend compressing, so long as you are getting noticeable reductions in the data to be transmitted. You're not going to "save" anything by making decompression slow.